# How to determine the CPU time of the execute of Makefile in linux or Unix?

Tags: linux, make, time, profiling

below is my Makefile using to execute my numerical code.I would like to know the time taken by the CPU to execute these C programmes.

```
#Makefile

LDFLAGS       = -DN_DIM=3
#LDFLAGS       = -DN_DIM=3  -DDEBUG=5

LIBS          = -lstdc++

#CC            = icc -O3 -xT -parallel -fp-model source
#CC            = icc -O3 -xT -parallel
CC            = icc -O3
#CC            = g++ -O3
#CC            = g++ -Wall


PROGRAM       = fem_pzt

OBJS          = pzcord.o       chg_stdi.o  element.o  gl2loc.o      print.o \
                add.o          force.o     solve.o    hexa_shape.o  clear.o \
                alloc.o        form_k.o    input.o    emsolve.o     hexa_bmatx.o \
                gauss_const.o  fatstep.o   newmark.o  mmatx.o



$(PROGRAM) : $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(LIBS) -o $@ $^

.cpp.o:
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -c $<

clean:
    rm -f $(OBJS) $(PROGRAM)
```

Comment: You cannot execute a Makefile. You can start the make program and have it interpret the Makefile, possible invoking commands on the way. If you want to time the execution of `make` use `time make target`. If you want to time execution of individual invocation lines specified in the Makefile insert `time` before the actual command (after the <key>TAB</key>before e.g. `$(CC)`). What of these do you want to do and what is the actual problem?

Answer (score 3):

You need to execute 'time' command.

Here is an example of how much time it takes to execute 'updatedb' command

```
root ~ $ time updatedb 
real    0m0.047s
user    0m0.015s
sys     0m0.029s
root ~ $
```